# Calculate a vector between 2 D3DXVECTOR3 independent of distance

Tags: c++, math, directx-9, direction, d3dx

So here's my scenario: I have a spaceship game, each spaceship can target another ship and fire torpedoes and the torpedo needs a directional vector to travel along, the vector needs to be independent of the distance.

I'm looking to create a method that returns a `D3DXVECTOR3` constructed like so:

`D3DXVECTOR3 TargetVector(D3DXVECTOR3 *target, D3DXVECTOR3 *firer)`

Has anyone got experience in this matter? It would be great if anyone could even point me towards any decent, easy to understand D3D mathematics tutorials as all I have found so far is based on rendering images rather than mathematical equations.

Thanks!

-Ryan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want a direction vector that starts from `firer` and points at `target` just subtract `firer` from `target` ie :

```
direction = target - firer;
```

There is [D3DXVec3Subtract](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb205519%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for it in D3DX lib.

If you want to have a unit normal, which is a vector that has a length of 1 then normalize it with [D3DXVec3Normalize](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb205515%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

So you will have :

```
D3DXVECTOR3 TargetVector(D3DXVECTOR3 *target, D3DXVECTOR3 *firer)
{
    D3DXVECTOR3 direction;
    D3DXVec3Subtract(&direction, target, firer);

    D3DXVec3Normalize(&direction, &direction);
    return direction;
}
```

Comment: Built without the ' & ' on target and firer, and the normalization will allow me to translate the torpedo like: ' torpedo[i].posVec3 += (torpedo[i].directionVec * torpedo[i].speed); ' right?

Comment: Yes assuming the `directionVec` has the right operator to multiply with a scalar.

Comment: directionVec is a D3DXVECTOR3, so I'm guessing that's a no-no? Also how to I use the code highlights in comments? It's been bugging me for a while now xD

Comment: Just use ` around the word to quote. There is probably a method in D3DX to multiply a vector and scalar. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb205518(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Consider moving to [DirectXMath](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2012/03/27/introducing-directxmath.aspx) rather than continuing to use the legacy D3DX math library. You could also use [XNAMath](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2011/02/23/xna-math-version-2-04.aspx) if you are not yet using the Windows 8.x SDK.